# password unavailability on AWS

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, configuration, password

I have one windows instance.
whenever I try to get the password of that instance.
It shows me the error 
[image: Password unavailable]
The instance is already running from last 24 hrs.
Is there any other way to retrieve the password.

Comment: Did you try stopping it then starting it again? Or creating another instance from the AMI / CloudFormation / etc?

Comment: I tried to start after stopping the instance and then get this error message. Its being started after that but there is no further activity.

Comment: I would suggest you get AWS developer support and ask them. It's pretty cheap, from about $50 a month, and you only need it for the month. Alternately you could detach the disk from the instance, create another instance including that disk as a data disk, and copy any data off.

Answer (score 0):

If you stop/terminate the instance and spawn a new one, it's usually resolved.

In my experience, it has happened when a custom AMI is in a bad state, and Windows cannot start. So I would advise checking the AMI.

Answer (score 0):

Did you deploy the instance using an AWS provided AMI or custom AMI?  If you used a custom AMI, did you make any changes to the local Administrator account?